# Unable to change the cell values when work sheet is in protected mode in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to change the particular cell values based on another cell values when the sheet is protected. code is working fine when the sheet is unprotected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim na As String, crow As Integer
    Dim subprocesmname As String
    Dim rng1 As Range

    subprocesmname = "Abbvie"
    na = "N/A"
    crow = ActiveCell.Row
    'MsgBox crow
'cell position C3
        If Worksheets(1).Range("C" & crow) = subprocesmname Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
            Worksheets(1).Range(("H" & crow), ("I" & crow)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Worksheets(1).Range(("H" & crow), ("I" & crow)) = na
            Worksheets(1).Range(("H" & crow), ("I" & crow)).Locked = True
            ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
        Else
            If (Worksheets(1).Range("H" & crow) = na And Worksheets(1).Range("H" & crow) = na) Then
                ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
                Worksheets(1).Range(("H" & crow), ("I" & crow)).Interior.Color = xlNone
                Worksheets(1).Range(("H" & crow), ("I" & crow)).Locked = False
                Worksheets(1).Range(("H" & crow), ("I" & crow)).Delete
                ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
            End If

        End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change some cells by VBA code when sheet is protected you need to set `userInterfaceOnly parameter to true` in this way:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect "password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

As a result you can change cells from VBA code while user can't change cells manually in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
```

and then you change cell values at worksheet(1)
Is the activesheet when unprotecting the cells worksheet(1)?

If not then change:

```
Worksheets(1).Unprotect "password"
```